# Onedrive API - One of the provided arguments is not acceptable error received when listing children of a document library

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm attempting to retrieve the contents of a folder in a SharePoint Document Library using the OneDrive REST API.

We are following [this documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/list.htm) here:

The call that I construct is:

`GET https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/Lindson'sTeam/_api/v2.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/children`

This yields an error response:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "One of the provided arguments is not acceptable."
    }
}
```

Why would this occur?

I have verified that the item we are retrieving looks legitimate and has a child:

`https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/Lindson'sTeam/_api/v2.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}`

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://lindsonresources.sharepoint.com/sites/Lindson'sTeam/_api/v2.0/$metadata#items/$entity",
    "@odata.type": "#oneDrive.item",
    "@odata.id": "https://lindsonresources.sharepoint.com/sites/Lindson'sTeam/_api/v2.0/drives/b!OV23drIi2EizXnhHJCU_rOeDApiWGMlDiw3J9cj0Mn3ihNYXTtJDTrfFQJqwaQcd/items/012YJ4V7D6JK42P6B6LNAKDB4QLXMDMVG5",
    "@odata.editLink": "drives/b!OV23drIi2EizXnhHJCU_rOeDApiWGMlDiw3J9cj0Mn3ihNYXTtJDTrfFQJqwaQcd/items/012YJ4V7D6JK42P6B6LNAKDB4QLXMDMVG5",
    "createdBy": {
        "application": {
            "id": "cc15fd57-2c6c-4117-a88c-83b1d56b4bbe",
            "displayName": "Microsoft Teams Services"
        },
        "user": {
            "email": "charles@lindsonresources.onmicrosoft.com",
            "id": "08360f17-3074-44bd-84f1-04bbf19cf49f",
            "displayName": "Charles Lindson"
        }
    },
    "createdDateTime": "2017-08-10T13:52:05Z",
    "eTag": "\"{A7B94A7E-3EF8-405B-A187-905DD83654DD},1\"",
    "id": "012YJ4V7D6JK42P6B6LNAKDB4QLXMDMVG5",
    "lastModifiedBy": {
        "application": {
            "id": "cc15fd57-2c6c-4117-a88c-83b1d56b4bbe",
            "displayName": "Microsoft Teams Services"
        },
        "user": {
            "email": "charles@lindsonresources.onmicrosoft.com",
            "id": "08360f17-3074-44bd-84f1-04bbf19cf49f",
            "displayName": "Charles Lindson"
        }
    },
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-08-10T13:52:05Z",
    "name": "General",
    "parentReference": {
        "driveId": "b!OV23drIi2EizXnhHJCU_rOeDApiWGMlDiw3J9cj0Mn3ihNYXTtJDTrfFQJqwaQcd",
        "driveType": "documentLibrary",
        "id": "012YJ4V7F6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ",
        "path": "/drives/b!OV23drIi2EizXnhHJCU_rOeDApiWGMlDiw3J9cj0Mn3ihNYXTtJDTrfFQJqwaQcd/root:"
    },
    "webUrl": "https://lindsonresources.sharepoint.com/sites/Lindson%27sTeam/Shared%20Documents/General",
    "cTag": "\"c:{A7B94A7E-3EF8-405B-A187-905DD83654DD},0\"",
    "fileSystemInfo": {
        "createdDateTime": "2017-08-10T13:52:05Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-08-10T13:52:05Z"
    },
    "folder": {
        "childCount": 1
    },
    "size": 18615279
}
```

Comment: Hi ruelloehr - can you provide us with the SPRequestGuid header from the response that returns the bad request? At a glance your request looks ok so we'll have to drill in deeper.

Comment: @brad Sure thing:     The SPRequestGuid is: aa92129e-4097-4000-1e23-d12231af6bb9

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're hitting a bug in how the download URL for one of the child files is being generated. There's nothing you can do from your side, we're writing up a fix now and will get it deployed. I'll update this answer when it's resolved.

Comment: The fix for this is pretty much fully deployed, so hopefully your issue is now resolved.